# Can the line-height in <li>s be a bit taller?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css

I was joking with somebody earlier about [the line-spacing in their post](https://askubuntu.com/a/410233/449). There's nothing wrong with the content, it's just hard to read. This is very easy to reproduce; just compare:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores autem nemo iste quos esse obcaecati voluptatibus et voluptas tempora incidunt. Officiis, doloremque, minima, quasi eius aliquid amet delectus iste deserunt ipsam at ratione aliquam dolorem. Rem nulla error fugiat numquam aut neque iure dolores ullam? Maiores dicta eveniet vitae labore animi eligendi magni nesciunt repellat. Libero, ducimus dolorem id distinctio necessitatibus temporibus culpa aut maiores excepturi ea laudantium earum accusamus vero mollitia provident voluptatibus deleniti molestiae sed aliquid delectus. Alias!
>
> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores autem nemo iste quos esse obcaecati voluptatibus et voluptas tempora incidunt. Officiis, doloremque, minima, quasi eius aliquid amet delectus iste deserunt ipsam at ratione aliquam dolorem. Rem nulla error fugiat numquam aut neque iure dolores ullam? Maiores dicta eveniet vitae labore animi eligendi magni nesciunt repellat. Libero, ducimus dolorem id distinctio necessitatibus temporibus culpa aut maiores excepturi ea laudantium earum accusamus vero mollitia provident voluptatibus deleniti molestiae sed aliquid delectus. Alias!

The `line-height` on the standard `<p>` is 18.2px. Inside a `<li>` that shrinks to 16px. The bigger the block of text, the harder it becomes to read through.

Could the line-height be boosted back up please? Here's the current CSS to make it easier to track:

```
ol li, ul li {
    line-height: 16px;
}
```

Comment: That CSS code at the end looks like you were playing with your name ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have changed the line-height to both paragraph text and <li> to 1.3. The change is now on dev, will be on live after the next production build.

Comment: Smashing news, thank you! By the way, what's the best way to tag these things so that they get pushed in your general direction? There are a couple of others CSS issues I've posted over the last few weeks but I'm not sure if they're popping up at your end. Are you following a particular tag?

Comment: @Oli I have a filter for "design" and "bug" on meta sites. I'm just behind on fixing them :(

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean it like that. You do a great job putting up with us :) I'll checked they're tagged properly.

Comment: @Oli oh I didn't mean it like that either :) I'm actually fixing the backlogs of css bugs right now. If you tagged them with "design" and "bug" I'll definitely get to them.